# How to exclude record which creates cycle in data on same start_dt?

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

To identify cycle I can do
`select * from input A join input B on A.prv=B.cur and A.cur=B.prv` but
How to keep only one record in cycle having same start_dt? Except Prv and curr all columns are same for these records.I am using spark sql/Hive

```
Input

prv  cur  start_dt
A     B   2099-12-31
B     A   2099-12-31
P     Q   2018-12-31
Q     P   2018-12-31

Output (any of one record in cycle)
prv  cur  start_dt
A     B   2099-12-31
P     Q   2018-12-31
```

Comment: If you can use Spark dataframe API, you can try drop_duplicates by adding a temporary column with value of `sort_array(array(prv,cur))`. below pyspark syntax: `df.withColumn('k', F.expr('sort_array(array(prv,cur))')).drop_duplicates(subset=['start_dt', 'k'])`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have `Prv = Cur` record (such as `A, A, 2099-12-31`, then you could use:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM input A 
    JOIN input B ON A.prv=B.cur AND A.cur=B.prv
    WHERE A.prv > B.prv
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input data, you can do:

```
select i.*
from input i
where i.prv < i.cur;
```

More generally, if you do not have duplicates for *all* pairs:

```
select i.*
from input i
where i.prv < i.cur
union all
select i.*
from input i
where i.prv > i.cur and
      not exists (select 1
                  from input i2
                  where i2.prv = i.cur and
                        i2.cur = i.prv and
                        i2.start_dt = i.start_dt 
                 );
```

Or, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*
             row_number() over (partition by start_dt, least(prv, cur), greatest(prv, cur) order by start_dt) as seqnum
      from input i
     ) i
where seqnum = 1;
```

This might be the most efficient method in Hive.